# Linear algebra on python

Tags: python, numpy

i would like to use numpy.linalg.solve to solve a linear algebra equation, but i got an error message saying 'Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square'. Please shed some light thanks a lot !! here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy. linalg import solve

A = np.array([[3,-1,-1,0,0,0], [-1,4,-1,-1,0,0], [0,0,-1,-1,4,-1], [0,0,0,-1,-1,3]],float)

w = np.array([5,5,0,0],float)

v = solve(A,w)

print(v)
```

Comment: To do a solve operation, you have to invert matrix A, and only square matrices are invertible. If you want to solve the system inexactly, you can use an operation called the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) and then multiply that with v to get v.

Comment: @castle-bravo or he could use `numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, w)`

Comment: @jandob I was just about to implement a pseudo inverse function for him or her, but I see it's already been done for me. :)

Comment: @castle-bravo it's best to avoid computing the pseudoinverse explicitly, since it's computationally more expensive and less numerically stable than the SVD-based method used by `lstsq`

Comment: @jandob you can post your comment as the answer...

Answer (score 6):

As igavriil already wrote `numpy.linalg.solve` can only be used to find (the exact) solution for a well-determined system (i.e sqare coefficient matrix). 
If your system is under- or over-determined, there is usually no exact solution.

If you want to find an approximate solution, you can use `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. It uses a method called "least-squares-fitting" to find a solution that minimizes the overall error.

Answer (score 3):

What this error basically says is that the linear system cannot be solved explicitly. This is because you have 6 variables and only 4 equations. In other words the coefficient matrix must be a square matrix. 
The error is raised when:

```
max(a.shape[-2:]) != min(a.shape[-2:]):
```

Answer (score -1):

So if you want **A x = b** and A is not square, you can simply do:

```
A_pseudoinverse = np.linalg.pinv(A)
x = A_pseudoinverse @ b
```

It's the same as @jandjob's answer, or at least close enough.